# Open new page/tab and add content

Tags: php, javascript, html, yii, browser-tab

I read many posts but i couldn't find an answer to my question. I have a button on a webpage which is linked to a controller. This controller prepares some data and calls the view. In the view I have a php variable with this data.

I want to open a new page/tab and add the content of my php variable. The content of the variable is a SVG string which is readable by all browsers.

I know this is not possible in php. I need to use JavaScript, but how can i add the content of a php variable to a new tab???

**Note:** I have the string only in the php variable not in a file and I don't want to click again on a link to open a new tab.

Any ideas or solutions?

According to the first answer an example (doesnt work:()

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Test file
    </title>
    <script>
        var myWindow = window.open('','_newtab');
        myWindow.document.write($('myString').text());

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="display:none" id="myString">Das kommt auch auf die neue seite</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is not capable of doing that. You need Javascript. Or you define your button with `target blank`.

**Window open() Method** http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

**HTML  target Attribute** http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

JS example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    myWindow=window.open('', '_blank')
    myWindow.document.write($('#myString').text());
});
```

This will open a new window and write #myString content to it. You need to define #myString with your string or whatever you want to display. E.g.

```
<p id="myString">New window</p>
```

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/qBjVG/13/

Comment: it would be useless to add target blank to the button because he call a controller and not the next view... and there is no destination file wich i can open with window.open() from javascript because i have only the variable in php

Comment: Use javascript to open the new window on document load!

Comment: That looks like it was very close but it does not...:(

Comment: In the example at your link is a file called test.html i don't have a file and i don't want to create a file for that...yet ever many thanks for your effort

Comment: try the code which i have written in according to your answer and see by yourself...anyway many thanks for your effort

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17395/discussion-between-artworkad-and-chris)

Comment: sry i had no more time yesterday...i fixed this problem with a litl work around i wrote my output to a file and opend it with window.open('tempFile')